# ClientID via FindControl() different from Generated ID in html

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I have a literal defined in a usercontrol which is embedded in an aspx and itself embedded in a Masterpage.

this.Parent.FindControl("litError") returns me the control... but the client ID is "phContent_litError". It does find the control on the server side code...

When I look into the generated HTML, i see "ctl00_ctl00_phContent_litErrorPanel"

Is it normal ?

My question is because I added an initiator control ( button)  dynamically in the ajaxsettings of my ajaxmanager to update the litError... However, when there is an error, I update the litError.text... but It wouldnt update it on the browser... which led me to check the litError control...

Answer (score 0):

The server side find control has the ability to find the server controls by name and as you have observed are generated in the page in order to be unique. The is normal. Ad to why a field in an Ajax control is not updating, you would need to post more code.